# How to generate PDF offline with UWP

Tags: pdf, uwp, visual-studio-2017, itext, offline

I'm developing a UWP app for tablet and i need to generate a PDF with data from SQLite. I need to do this completely offline because where I will use the app there is no connection. What could I do?
I'd prefer not to use paid libraries like Syncfusion and XFinium so I'm trying to find an alternative solution.

I tried with iTextSharp but unfortunately I can't find a good documentation to render a complex PDF or to export a Bitmap generated from a Grid Component to a PDF File.

Comment: Unless you want to release your app as open source GPL, iTextSharp is more expensive than any other solution.

Comment: Unfortunately I think you are right. What kind of solution could be better? I read about Syncfusion, but I can't understand if I could create an entire PDF by code, because I have to generate a dynamic structure PDF starting from data and everything needs to work offline.

Answer (score 0):

Why not render your data into a webpage displayed with a `WebView` control?  Then you can use any permissive licensed javascript library to generate the PDF.

If it hasn't changed much, then you can only send text back and forth between your `WebView` and UWP app, but that's workable.  Your final PDF result can be read back as a base64 encoded string.

A very quick search found this one that seems easy to use and you can just download the source to put into your app:
https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

Comment: I think that it could work. Thanks for the source, I'll try this solution.

Comment: If this helped, you could upvote the answer.  If it worked, you could mark it as an answer...